# Using GPU with Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have python code that use Keras (with tensorflow backend)
I have trouble using my GPU to reduce processing time of my computations

I am using PyCharm to import my dependencies.
When I import tensorflow, my code run well but is very slow since it does not use GPU at all.

If I use tensorflow-gpu instead of basic tensorflow (I created a new Python env in which I have never imported the basic tensorflow), I get the following error :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UserName/PycharmProjects/MyProject/my-package/my_code.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyimagesearch.smallvggnet import SmallVGGNet
  File "C:\Users\UserName\PycharmProjects\MyProject\my-package\pyimagesearch\smallvggnet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\venv2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Notes :

- The error seems to appear when I have both keras and tensorflow-gpu imported
- Both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu use version 1.12
- Keras use version 2.2.4 (Tried with 1.6.0 too)
- Python 3.6 (Tried with 3.7 too)
- CUDA 10.0 (Tried with 9.0 too) and the associated cuDNN version
- As proposed [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-install-TensorFlow-to-use-with-PyCharm), I added path to CUDA & cuDNN bin folders to PyCharm project Content Root.
- My computer have two GPU :

  - Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (The basic one)
  - NVIDIA Quadro P1000 (The one I want to use)

What can I do to make this work ?

Comment: This may be due to mismatches between versions of Keras, tensorflow, CUDA, and cuDNN. I have a stable Windows configuration that uses Python3.6, Keras 2.2.2, tensorflow 1.10.0, CUDA 9.0, and cuDNN 5.1.10. I've heard about issues using tensorflow 1.12.0 with Windows, especially with Python3.7, but this configuration works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also make sure you have the appropriate nvidia drivers installed. There's some dependencies between the drivers and different CUDA/cuDNN versions

Comment: Why are you importing both keras and tensorflow? Tensorflow now includes a drop-in replacement for keras with `tensorflow.keras`, removing the need to have both installed independently.

Comment: You were right, it was probably a mismatches version. Using the Tensorflow drop-in replacement for keras as Jordan Singer proposed did the trick. Thanks all.

Comment: Note : When doing so, I had an error while saving a Keras model : `Cannot save keras model. h5py import errors`, manualy importing h5py solved the problem and everything works well.